# Emphasize purchased products & wishlisted products in Einstein Recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

We now have a use case where we need to get Einstein recommendation to emphasize products the customer has added to wishlist & previously purchased, before logics that personalize based on product attributes like category, etc.

Einstein out of the box doesn’t have such capability of emphasizing these products as far as I know. I’ve thought about below idea, and want to hear what you think, and please share solutions you have in mind if any:

Use custom contact attribute affinity for ‘WishlistItems’, and call below when customer adds an item to wishlist:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      

   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);    

   _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "INSERT_EMAIL_OR_UNIQUE_ID",

        "details":    {

        "WishlistItems: "SKUID1", "SKUID2",  "SKUID3",  "SKUID4"

                       }

}]);    

   _etmc.push(["trackPageView"]);   

</script>
```

Add custom attribute to product catalog for: WishlistItems: “Insert SKUID”.

Thereafter configure:

Scenario of: tag_WishlistItems is same as user affinity
Rule for: emphasize products whose WishlistItems= sames as user affinity

Further, we can also emphasize products purchased with similar method as above. I’m not sure if it’s a good practice to create custom tagged attributes on a SKUID level.

Looking forward to hearing what you think.

Comment: Products that have been purchased are by default excluded from all recommendations

Comment: Yes, we've deactivate that @EazyE